# Custom format for biblatex eventdate with day range

Tags: biblatex, datetime

How can I specify a custom date format in biblatex for `eventdate` in case a range of several days or weeks is specified?

Using `\thefield{eventday}` for example only returns the first day of the range, but not the last. I tried it that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{eventdate}{%
  \thefield{eventyear}%
  \space
  \mkbibmonth{\thefield{eventmonth}}%
  \space%
  \thefield{eventday}}

\begin{filecontents*}{database.bib}
@inproceedings{Baker2011,
 author = {Baker, Christopher R. and Dolan, John M. and Wang, Shige and Litkouhi, Bakhtiar B.},
 bookpagination = {page},
 booktitle = {2011 IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation},
 doi = {10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980355},
 eventdate = {2011-05-09/2011-05-13},
 eventtitle = {2011 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA 2011)},
 isbn = {978-1-61284-386-5},
 keywords = {software architecture},
 pages = {6071--6077},
 publisher = {IEEE},
 location = {Piscataway, NJ},
 title = {Toward adaptation and reuse of advanced robotic software},
 venue = {Shanghai, China},
 year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{database}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography{}

\end{document}
```

What I need is an event date in the format 2010 Aug 10-12.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you tried?

Comment: @Jan added the example

Comment: please add some more information.  We do need to have a MWE (Minimal Working Example) from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`.  In your case, your document should note all BibLaTeX relevant entries, as well, as a incorporated BibTeX-file with at least one BibTeX-entry containing your mentioned `eventdate`.  You can include that BibTex-file by `begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}@Article ... \end{filecontents}`.

Comment: @jan There is an MWE now

Comment: Are you using a particular `babel` language in your actual document?

Comment: Sorry, to ask again: What is the desired format for other dates should they be as detailed as year, month, day? What for example about `urldate`? Do you use any other date options, or can we assume you want all others to be the default `comp` format with no further change?

Comment: @moewe I don't care much about localization, as documents will be inherently English. The intended format is below the example: `2010 Aug 10` or `2012 Mar 13-20` for full dates. Otherwise only the year. It might be possible to change the global date option for all dates in the bibliography.

Comment: OK, I was asking because by default all dates use the `comp` style. So if I were to change the `comp` style *all* date formats would change to your desired format (which you only stated as desired for `eventdate`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following redefinition of date internals (note that you will have to wrap it in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{<doclang>}`). This changes the setting for `comp` dates. So it will alter more than just your `eventdate`s. Most dates are `comp` by default, notable exceptions being `labeldate=year` and `urldate=short`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
        \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
        \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@long#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \blx@metadateinfo{#2}%
    \iffieldundef{#2year}
      {\blx@nounit}
      {\printtext[#2date]{%
         \datecircaprint
         \iffieldundef{#2season}
           {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}}
           {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}}%
         \dateeraprint{#2}%
         \dateuncertainprint
         \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
           {}
           {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
             {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
             {\bibdaterangesep
              \enddatecircaprint
              \iffieldundef{#2season}
                {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                  {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2endday}}
                    {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                  {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
              \enddateuncertainprint
              \dateeraprint{#2}}}}}%
  \endgroup}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{Baker2011,
  author         = {Baker, Christopher R. and Dolan, John M. and Wang, Shige and Litkouhi, Bakhtiar B.},
  bookpagination = {page},
  booktitle      = {2011 IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation},
  doi            = {10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980355},
  eventdate      = {2011-05-09/2011-05-13},
  eventtitle     = {2011 IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA 2011)},
  isbn           = {978-1-61284-386-5},
  keywords       = {software architecture},
  pages          = {6071--6077},
  publisher      = {IEEE},
  location       = {Piscataway, NJ},
  title          = {Toward adaptation and reuse of advanced robotic software},
  venue          = {Shanghai, China},
  year           = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. How can I get this to apply also for urldate?

Comment: Sorry, I have to get back to this. I just noticed that for eventdate fields this creates something like: `2011 May 9–2011 May 13`. Do you know how to get this to print the minimal range in all cases?

Comment: @languitar I just checked with my MWE and I get '2011 May 9-13' for `eventdate` in the MWE. Can you ask a new question with an MWE about that maybe?

Comment: thanks, done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355344/construct-minimal-date-range-in-biblatex-style

Comment: @languitar I'm sorry, it should have of course been `urldate=comp`, from which you can of course pass to `alldates=comp`.

Comment: With this MWE I get the following error: `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \dateeraprintpre{}\stripzeros {\thefield {}}`

Comment: @user2513149 That probably means your `biblatex` system is outdated.

Comment: Actually, I checked and `eventdate = {2011-05-09/2011-05-13}` works perfectly without adding `\DefineBibliographyExtras` section. Is there any way to localize month names in the ouput?

Comment: @user2513149 Well, the purpose of `\DefineBibliographyExtras` here is to make sure that a certain special date format is used. If you want the usual date format, you don't need that block. By default all dates are localised, so you should get localised month names as well. If that does not work for you I suggest you ask a new question with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that shows what is going wrong.