# Construct minimal date range in biblatex style

Tags: biblatex

I am using the solution presented in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347797/custom-format-for-biblatex-eventdate-with-day-range) for a custom date format. Unfortunately, date ranges, e.g. for `eventdate` results in a very verbose `2009 Sept. 16–2009 Sept. 18` format. It would be nice if only a minimal date range was produced, which skips the repetition of year and month if possible.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{alldates = long}
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldbibstring{#1}
      {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
      {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
        \mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
        \iffieldundef{#3}{}{\space}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}}%
%
\protected\gdef\lbx@us@mkdaterangetrunc@long#1#2{%
  \iffieldundef{#2year}
    {}
    {\datecircaprint
     \printtext[#2date]{%
       \iffieldundef{#2season}
         {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2year}{#2month}{#2day}%
          \dateeraprint{#2}}
         {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2year}{#2season}}%
          \dateeraprint{#2}}%
       \dateuncertainprint
       \iffieldundef{#2endyear}
         {}
         {\iffieldequalstr{#2endyear}{}
           {\mbox{\bibdaterangesep}}
           {\bibdaterangesep
            \enddatecircaprint
            \iffieldundef{#2season}
              {\iffieldsequal{#2year}{#2endyear}
                {\iffieldsequal{#2month}{#2endmonth}
                  {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{}{#2endday}}
                  {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
                {\csuse{mkbibdate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endmonth}{#2endday}}}
              {\csuse{mkbibseasondate#1}{#2endyear}{#2endseason}}%
            \enddateuncertainprint
            \dateeraprint{#2}}}}}%
 }%
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inproceedings{Bannach2009,
 author = {Bannach, David and Amft, Oliver and Lukowicz, Paul},
 booktitle = {Smart Sensing and Context},
 eventdate = {2009-09-16/2009-09-18},
 eventtitle = {Smart Sensing and Context (EuroSCC 2009)},
 pages = {135--148},
 publisher = {Springer},
 title = {Automatic Event-Based Synchronization of Multimodal Data Streams from Wearable and Ambient Sensors},
 venue = {Guilford, UK},
 year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You do realise you are missing the `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` from my answer, right? Plus, you added in empty curly brackets where you need none. Copy the *entire* suggested code as it is in the answer and don't change it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was confused when I told you to use `urldate=long` (I have clarified my comment on the other answer), so you probably want `alldates = comp`.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted this from a bbx file, where I thought makeatletter etc wasn't necessary?

Comment: Yes, it is not, but in your MWE it is certainly missing and part of the problem: Add `\makeatletter` back in *and* go for `alldates=comp`, and you get the desired format. With spurious spaces mind you, those come from all the empty curly brackets that you(? your editor?) inserted after macros without arguments.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you want an accepted answer, please add the `alldates=comp` as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I gave in [Custom format for biblatex eventdate with day range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/347797/35864) modifies the output for `comp` dates. So we need

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{alldates = comp}
```

to benefit from the change for all dates.