# How to change the eventdate format in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am new to `biblatex` and I need to change the eventdate-format in the proceedings.

I have created my own `.bbx` file based on `numeric-comp`.
Therefore the `eventdate`, I defined as following in the `.bib` file

```
@proceedings{Tagungsbeitrag,
editor = {N. Name},
title = {Title},
year = {1999},
eventtitle = {Eventtitle},
eventdate = {1999-10-07/1999-10-08},
venue = {Irgendwo},
language = {german},
series = {series},
OPTorganization = {•},
publisher = {publisher},
location = {location},
OPTisbn = {•},
pages = {S. 1--2},
OPTpagetotal = {•},
OPTdoi = {•},
}
```

looks like:

> Name, N.: Title. Eventtitle, 7.-8. Okt. 1999 Irgendwo. In: series. location: publisher, S. 1-2.

**I want change the `eventdate`** from 7.-8. **Okt.** 1999 to 7.-8. **10.** 1999

i.e., Okt. --> 10. so that I get

> Name, N.: Title. Eventtitle, 7.-8. 10. 1999 Irgendwo. In: series. location: publisher, S. 1-2.

**Is there an easy way to do this in the `.bbx` file?** Like

```
%\DeclareFieldFormat{eventdate}{
...
}
```

I have read the other [posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347797/custom-format-for-biblatex-eventdate-with-day-range?newreg=79c922b1655d4fa584df6d624f1de9a0) but can not find a solution.

I use following code in the preamble to load `biblatex`.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=my-style %numeric-comp
,sorting=none, language=autobib,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex} 
\bibliography{my-lit.bib} 
\begin{document}
\printbibliography[title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format of the `eventdate` can be controlled with the `eventdate` option. The available values are documented in the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for `date` (p. 53).

> 7.-8. 10. 1999

corresponds to the setting `eventdate=terse` in German.

If you want to load the option in your `.bib` file, you can say

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{eventdate=terse}
```

Note that a `@proceedings` is the type for an entire volume of conference proceedings (*Tagungsband*). That type normally does not have an author and page numbers. If you want to cite a specific paper (*Tagungsbeitrag*), then you should use `@inproceedings` (as in the example below).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=99,
  eventdate=terse]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{tagungsbeitrag,
  author     = {N. Name},
  title      = {Title},
  year       = {1999},
  eventtitle = {Eventtitle},
  eventdate  = {1999-10-07/1999-10-08},
  venue      = {Irgendwo},
  language   = {german},
  booktitle  = {Proceedings of the Blah},
  publisher  = {Publisher},
  location   = {Location},
  pages      = {1-2},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{salam,tagungsbeitrag}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Abdus Salam. „Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions“. In: Elementary particle theory. Relativistic groups and analyticity. Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium (Aspenäsgarden, Lerum, 19.–25.05.1968). Hrsg. von Nils Svartholm. Stockholm: Almquist & Wiksell, 1968, S. 367–377.//N. Name. „Title“. In: Proceedings of the Blah. Eventtitle (Irgendwo, 07.–08.10.1999). Location: Publisher, 1999, S. 1–2.]

Comment: Many Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. You saved my day

Comment: @Becks_jn Glad I could help. May I ask you to consider combining several code snippets as in your question into one self-contained and immediately compilable code example (as in this answer) in your future questions? While your question was quite understandable without a so-called MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), it is much easier for people to get started helping you if they have something to start from.

Comment: @moewe Sort of off-topic here, but not too much. Do you see any chance or interest in something in line with formatting directives being made available also for dates format? (In the sense of being able to write something like `\printeventdate[terse]`).

Comment: @gusbrs No idea if that can be implemented easily, but if you think it makes sense (I would agree), you can open a ticket at the bug tracker.

Comment: @moewe I do have a concrete use case. But I do also know dates are very tricky. That's why I ask your opinion and if there's demand by others.

Comment: @gusbrs If you have a use case, fire away. I doubt that a lot of people will be interested. But if it is easy to implement, I'm all for it. I always found it a bit weird that dates can only be controlled through options. I can imagine that it would be convenient from time to time to be able to specify a certain style only locally.

Comment: @moewe I'll prepare a feature request then. Thanks!